# Where to place text field filtering code in file dependent upon if statement

Tags: swift, uitextfield, character

I'm looking to enable this function according to specific text fields. For example, if textfield1.isEditing == true, have the function proceed. However, I have been unable to enable this feature in or out of the brackets of viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning. What should I be doing instead?

```
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn     range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
```

Update 1:
for example, I'm looking to have this function perform only when Credits1TF is being edited. However, when I run this code, any character is passed through this function and shows up in the text field. I've moved this piece of code in and out of viewDidLoad before this to alter the results, but all characters are able to be entered regardless.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    if Credits1TF.isEditing == true
    {
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn     range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters
            let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

            return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Show the whole method and show some context. Where is this code? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Kindly try to improve your question. because even you have edited but we are still not clear, what exactly you are talking about

Comment: I'm unsure where to place this code in my file to enable specific text fields to take advantage of this filtering function.

Comment: Delegate methods (like this one) can't be nested inside any other methods.

Comment: I'm thankful for the answer, rmaddy! While I've decided to approach my problem in a different manner, is there any way to have a delegate method inside another function? Or is this a fact?

Comment: No, delegate methods can't be nested.